# How to "trick" C preprocessor into accepting any part of a function/variable etc. as a token?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Note that I'm trying to modify existing code, written by someone else, so answers from other similar questions most likely don't apply, as they could kick off the code with macro functions oriented coding mentality in mind, making preprocessing acrobatics much easier, which isn't the case for me.

So this is what I want to do.  Let's say I have 1 function and 1 variable:

```
void Foo1(void);
int Foo1 = 0;
```

I want to turn them into:

```
void FOO1(void);
int FOO1 = 0;
```

Now as everyone knows, doing

```
#define Foo FOO
```

will not work as the C preprocessor will not treat Foo out of Foo1 as a single token but rather, it will treat Foo1, the whole of it, as a token.

So I need to somehow "trick" the C preprocessor into believing Foo is a token, then work on it.

I tried this:

```
#define a_random_thing Foo
#define Foo FOO
```

naively believing preprocessor will consider "Foo" a product of "a_random_thing" after expansion, and then perform another round of expansion on "Foo".

That sadly and obviously didn't work.

So what exactly should I do?

The code I'm working on is an updated library, and tons of the variable names and function names were modified ever so slightly — just enough to gave me 100+ compilation errors; very thoughtful on their part. I'm trying to make it backward compatible.

If what I'm trying to accomplish is not possible, please also tell me, thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that you cannot fool the preprocessor that way. Let's wait for other answers. Meanwhile I recommend to add some background, so that in case we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem you might find help in a more indirect way than you thought of. (More details than the description you did provide. Maybe a few examples.)

Comment: Are you thinking of a specific question which is not a dulicate of this? I ask because saying "this is not a duplicate" without details will just get people to try extra hard proving you wrong, which distracts them from trying to actually help you.

Comment: I second this sounding like an XY problem. The question of how to attain compatibility with both versions of your library may in fact be answered in a way that doesn't require the fooling the preprocessor at all. Focusing on what you believe to be the solution rather than the actual problem can be a hindrance.

Comment: I have seen libraries having their API names changed intentionally to cause these errors, with sound reasons. One of them is that the behaviour has changed subtly but relevantly so that using it in previous ways is not recommended. The suppliers force you to think about each use of their software. And that might actually be a kindness, a feature.

Comment: Please list or at least provide a count of all "before->after" pairs. Depending on the number it might be feasible to do similar to what you imagine (I have an idea for low numbers).

Comment: There cannot be function and variable with the same name in the same scope

Comment: @Yunnosch where did I say "this is not a duplicate"?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I guess I have no way of convincing you this is not an "XY" problem, which I have no idea what the meaning is

Comment: @M.M What are you trying to say?

Comment: @cream_pi if you don't know what an XY problem is, how are you sure this isn't one?

Comment: @cream_pi - You literally got a link to the definition of an XY problem in the first comment of this post. And accusing me of refusal to accept the reality of this question while stubbornly ignoring the possibility you are doing it yourself, well that's rich.

Comment: I would recommend you just port your code to new version. 100+ errors is not much, and and if you just need to replace names, the work is fairly straightforward. It would be more futureproof way, than trying to maintain some kind of workaround.

Comment: Here, first line before the edit: "First of all, before mods flagging this as a duplicate, please make sure you finished reading this question."

Comment: If you do not know what a XY problem is, why not read the link I provided.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really possible unless you go ahead and define foo1, foo2, foo3...

You simply can't split `foo1` into two different pre-processor tokens, which would be required in order to solve the problem variably.

The closest thing you can do is `#define foo(n) FOO##n` and call it as `foo(1)` to get `FOO1`.

...or you could probably just do search & replace in a text editor.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, Danke sehr!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this won't work is because tokenization happens in the lexing phase of the compilation process. In this phase, the C compiler will parse the sequence of bytes as per C's lexical rules to create tokens (individual elements of the code: keywords, names for variables and functions, operations like +-*/, etc.).

The lexing phase works before the C pre-processor. At this time, the pre-processor looks for tokens matching the macro definition, and replaces them. Already, what your program will have are tokens called `foo1`, and a macro defining `FOO`.

I would suggest you look at string replacement tools `sed`/`awk` to solve your problem.